# Create a API endpoint in NodeJS to make REST api call and return a JSON data

Tags: node.js, express, curl

So I need to create a endpoint i.e. A GET request in NodeJS which will make a curl call to another api and return a data. I am using native method of NodeJS to make curl call using https module. But I am not getting any response when I hit my nodeJS api (i.e. /api/mailers/campaigns). If I try to print curl response in console it returns me correct data. Is there anything I am missing?

Basically for security purpose I will hit my nodejs endpoint from my frontend

```
const app = express();
const http = require("https");

app.get('/api/mailers/campaigns', (req, res) => {
    var chunks = [];
    var options = {
        "method": "GET",
        "hostname": "api.mailerlite.com",
        "port": null,
        "path": "/api/v2/campaigns",
        "headers": {
            "x-mailerlite-apikey": "api_key",
            "content-type":"application/json"
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        

        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", function () {
            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
           return body.toString();
        });
    });


    req.end();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

No response I got from any one but Genius me found a solution by self :P
Just need to send response in req.end() method and it works fine

```
resp.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    res.send(JSON.parse(body))
});
```

Complete solution

```
app.get('/api/mailers/campaigns', async(req, res) => {
    var chunks = [];
    var options = {
        "method": "GET",
        "hostname": mailerBaseUrl,
        "path": "/api/v2/campaigns?limit=100",
        "headers": {
            "x-mailerlite-apikey": mailerApiKey
        }
    };

    var req = await http.request(options, function (resp) {
        resp.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        resp.on("end", function () {
            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            res.send(JSON.parse(body))
        });
    });
    req.end();
});
```